# How to view the value of a hive variable?

Tags: sql, apache, hql, hive

How do you view the value of a hive variable you have set with the command "SET a = 'B,C,D'"? I don't want to use the variable- just see the value I have set it to. Also is there a good resource for Hive documentation like this? The Apache website is not very helpful.

Comment: https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/60309/working-with-variables-in-hive-hive-shell-and-beel.html

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Found my answer. The answer is simply:
"Set a;"
Stupid syntax IMO, but thats the way it is.

Comment: That's the most stupid syntax I have ever seen but Thank you!

Comment: cannot use this in HUE unfortunately

Answer (score 12):

Another way to view the value of a variable is via the `hiveconf` variable

```
hive> select ${hiveconf.a};
```

where `a` is the variable name

To see the values of all the variables, simply type

```
set -v
```

Answer (score 11):

The bellow will set the value of zzz

```
hive> set zzz=5;
```

To see what value in zzz use the bellow command

```
hive> set zzz;
zzz=5
```